# Better way to Inject multiple interfaces into multiple classes without calling base .Net

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

If I have multiple different classes that are being refactored to implement the same multiple interfaces, is there a nicer way to inject those interfaces into those classes without having to specify in each implementations constructor the same interfaces?

Currently as I understand it, it works as

```
public abstract class Shape {
    protected ILogger logger {get; set;}
    protected IEventService service {get;set;}

    public Shape(ILogger logger, IEventService service){
        this.logger = logger;
        this.service = service;    
    }
}

public class Square : Shape{

    public Square(ILogger logger, IEventService service) : base(logger,service){}

}
```

However, with more interfaces and multiple children this turns into a lot of copy/pasting in your code.

Is there a way to design this so that a child class doesn't have to specify the injected interfaces, to make refactoring multiple classes cleaner?

I've tried the standard abstract class however that requires you to send through the injected implementations.

Comment: No, and this has nothing to do with DI. If there's no parameterless constructor, the child constructor must call one of the available parent constructors

Comment: `with more interfaces and multiple children this turns into a lot of copy/pasting in your code.` that's a design smell of [Constructor Over-injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/). It says the class is trying to do far too many things and needs redesigning. Why does a Shape, which is typically a DTO, need access to an event service?

Comment: Constructor Over-Injection is definitely the problem, thanks for putting a name to it. Refactoring to something else is something else is what I'm wondering about at the moment, event services and logging service are both used for different types of logging at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Dependency Injection framework you'd be able to write code like this:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    [Inject]
    protected ILogger logger { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    protected IEventService service { get; set; }
}

[Factory(typeof(Square))]
public class Square : Shape { }

[Factory(typeof(ILogger))]
public class Logger : ILogger { }

[Factory(typeof(IEventService))]
public class EventService : IEventService { }
```

Then to resolve and inject the code would look like this:

```
IContext context = Injectivity.Context.CreateRoot();
context.Register(this.GetType().Assembly);
Square square = context.Resolve<Square>();
```

This is all in a Dependency Injection framework I wrote, but there are good well maintained ones available.

Comment: I'm using the default .net core DI functionality, but I will look into whether theres a suitable framework like you mentioned that could help

Answer (score 0):

After some reading into what Panagiotis linked - [Constructor Over-Injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/)
I'm going to refactor the codebase so services more closely follow SRP, as well as adding in some [Aggregate Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) to cut down on the amount of items that need to be injected into constructors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).